# How does the jQuery .unbind() function work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some background: the JavaScript function `.removeEventListener()` requires an explicit declaration of which handler you want to remove, while jQuery's `.unbind()` will automatically remove all event listeners associated with a given element.

Taking a look at the jQuery source code, i'm pretty confused as to how the `.unbind()` function is actually doing what it's doing. How is it removing all possible handlers associated with a given element, if it doesn't know them by name?

Edit: Sorry if I wasn't clear. My question is "how does the JavaScript source code for .unbind() work?" I know how to use .unbind(). I want to know why it works.

Comment: the default value is assigned.

Comment: Since jQuery acts as a proxy for the underlying events system, it'd be simple to keep around a list of callbacks attached to where.

Comment: If works just like the now preferred `off()`

Comment: @alex does jQuery keep a list of callbacks? I'd be interested to see where in the source code that's occurring.

Comment: @raorao Last time I looked at the code, many years ago, it did. You could get at them via `data("events")`. I don't believe that works anymore though.

Answer (score 2):

If you see [jquery-1.11.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js) the you find your answer

`jQuery.removeEvent` is called lastly, when you call `unbind()`

```
jQuery.removeEvent = document.removeEventListener ?
    function( elem, type, handle ) {
        if ( elem.removeEventListener ) {
            elem.removeEventListener( type, handle, false );
        }
    } :
    function( elem, type, handle ) {
        var name = "on" + type;

        if ( elem.detachEvent ) {

            // #8545, #7054, preventing memory leaks for custom events in IE6-8
            // detachEvent needed property on element, by name of that event, to properly expose it to GC
            if ( typeof elem[ name ] === strundefined ) {
                elem[ name ] = null;
            }

            elem.detachEvent( name, handle );
        }
    };
```

For egs try [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind),

```
$('#selector').unbind('click',handler);
```

Above has `elem`,`type`, and `handle` in 
[removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) : `function( elem, type, handle )`

Here

1. elem=$('#selector')
2. type=click
3. handle=handler

Step by step call of `unbind()` see [jquery-1.11.1.js source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js)

1. `$('#selector').unbind('click') // calling unbind function line 8490`
2. which calls [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off) `// line 8491(calling) => line 5201(function definition)`
3. Now calling `event.remove()` `// line 5229 => line 4374`
4. which calls `removedata()` finally where `removeEventListener` function is called

Comment: I saw this, although I'm still not sure what's going on here. i don't understand the question mark on line 1, or where the handle variable is coming from.

Comment: why would they use `strundefined` instead of `"undefined"`?

Comment: Again see that `js` you will find ` **General-purpose constants** `strundefined = typeof undefined,` which is globally used.

Comment: @RohanKumar: That doesn't really answer my question. When would `typeof undefined` ever not return `"undefined"`? (not that this is at all related to OP's question)

Comment: This isn't very interesting at all, we all knew jQuery was using removeEventListener, but how the events are iterated would probably be more interesting, and jQuery keeps a reference to all bound events internally so they can be iterated with a `for (type in events) { ...` etc. and all be removed with one call to unbind / off.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but i still don't think it answers my question. You can call .unbind() without a defined type or handle, and it still works -- in that case, it would remove all handles associated with all events. I'm wondering how that process works.

Comment: @raorao see the step-by-step calls in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#foo" ).unbind();
```

Unbind with no argument removes all handlers attached to the elements.

```
var handler = function() {
alert( "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." );
};
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", handler );
$( "#foo" ).unbind( "click", handler );
```

By specifying the click event type, only handlers for that event type will be unbound

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear. My question isn't "how do I use the $.unbind() function?" its "how does $.unbind() work under the hood?"

Comment: Thats cool. I think @Rohan Kumar answered your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is jquery unbind remove only event handlers who bound with jquery bind, it cache all event handler bound by .bind and when you call .unbind('click') it unbind all handlers.
example:
if you write

```
function click(){}
el.bind('click', click);
el[0].addEventListener('click', click);
```

and then
 `el.unbind('click')`
or 
`el.unbind('click', click);`
it will remove only function bound by .bind,
so if you use jquery you should alway use .bind to prevent unuse  handlers

Answer (score 0):

One more think
if you write

`el[0].addEventListener('click', click);`

and then

```
el.unbind('click', click);
```

jquery will remove event listener by using `el[0].removeEventListener('click', click)`
but if you use just

```
el.unbind('click');
```

jquery will not remove your listener